# How can I make the Geany editor's tab key behave like Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, geany

In the Eclipse IDE, when you are editing inside a pair of parentheses, brackets or double quotes, you can press the tab key to move the cursor out of the brackets.

Is there a way to configure Geany to behave the same way?

For example, in Eclipse:

- `int main(`**`|`**`)`  [before pressing tab]
- `int main()`**`|`**  [after pressing tab]

Comment: Geany is my editor of choice & I'm not aware of any functionality like this.

Comment: Same here.. that's why Im looking to implement this functionality somehow. much better than using arrow keys/end button.